# Comparison BTC and ETH uncomfirmed transactions queue

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

When I compare BTC mempool count and ETH transaction queues, ETH queues are much larger. I would appreciate explanations why it is so.

*BTC mempool count

https://blockchain.info/ja/charts/mempool-count

*ETH transaction queue

https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx

Comment: They are completely different networks, there's no real direct comparison. ETH just has a lot more going on

Comment: ETH has a shorter confirmation time and lower volume (correct?). Then why ETH has a higher number of transactions in queue?

Comment: ETH has a significantly higher transaction volume, much higher than the additional speed granted by a faster block time.

Comment: BTC: https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions ETH: https://etherscan.io/chart/tx Are these two charts fair comparison?

Comment: But Yahoo finance has the other way round: BTC https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD ETH: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ETH-USD/history?p=ETH-USD why?

Comment: That's trade volume. You're looking at a comparison of transaction volume. Trading happens largely off chain, so does not reflect well in the transaction volume.

Comment: What does "off chain" mean? Mean "outside the exchanges"?

Answer (score 2):

The ethereum chain has a far higher number of transactions than the BTC chain. This is mostly due to ethereum's faster block time, and the presence of many thousand smart contracts on ethereum, which all contribute to more transactions.

In the comments, it seems like you are comparing the transaction volume charts to the trade volume charts.

Trading of BTC and ETH happens largely on exchanges. These exchanges have trading engines that execute all trades within the exchange itself, and not on the blockchains. That is to say, if User A sells to User B, there is no corresponding blockchain transaction transferring those coins. Instead, both users have accounts on the exchange which are debited and credited. A blockchain transfer only takes place during deposits and withdrawals.

Through this process, many thousands of trades can take place without ever reflecting on the blockchain. However, interactions with smart contracts must happen on the blockchain, and contribute towards the total transaction volume.

Comment: Maybe I am confused. What is "blockchain transaction" in your explanation?

Comment: "If User A sells to User B," but these transactions need to be validated by proof of work to prevent double spending. Is this statement correct?

Comment: "For example, if Sean sends one bitcoin to John, this transaction will remain “unconfirmed” until the next block is created. " (https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/confirmations/)

Comment: That's only when sending bitcoin between people. On exchanges, you send your coins to the exchange. The exchange has an internal ledger. Trades are executed by updating the balances in this internal ledger. This part does not touch the blockchain at all, and involves no proof of work.

Comment: For example, Kraken says: "Bitcoin deposits should be credited after 6 network confirmations (normally about 1 hr but can be delayed when Bitcoin network is slow)".(https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/4e64k4/how_long_does_it_take_to_get_a_btc_transaction_on/)

Comment: That's about deposits (moving coins to the exchange), not trades. Trades inside an exchange is just flipping some database entries (incrementing an account balance for one person, decrementing for another), which aren't reflected on chain. From the blockchain's perspective, all exchange user's coins are owned (or at least controlled) by the exchange's keys.