# Off chain transaction on exchange

Tags: exchanges, off-chain, fiat

Are cryptocurrency exchanges uses off chain transactions?And if yes when does they used?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/76174/5406

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Whenever one of their customers sends money from that customer's account to the account of another of the customers of the same exchange.

Whenever a customer with an account deposits or withdraws money in another currency.

Comment: This happen via payment channels.Am i right?

Comment: Not via "payment channels" in the normal sense. Just numbers in proprietary records that are nothing to do with the Bitcoin network or blockchain.